# regular expression: find and replace each match

Tags: regex, yahoo-pipes

I need to change the elements that surround some contents in a string, leaving the content as is. I'm doing it with a regular expression, but when I replace using the positional parameter ($1), it only uses the first match.

For example, if I have this string:

```
&lt;strong&gt;I want&lt;/strong&gt; to change &lt;i&gt;this&lt;/i&gt; text, 
but &lt;u&gt;I can't&lt;/u&gt;. &lt;div class="question"&gt;Why?&lt;/div&gt;.
```

I want to change it to:

```
<strong>I want</strong> to change <i>this</i> text, 
but <u>I can't</u>. <div class="question">Why?</div>.
```

But I can only get this:

```
<strong>I want<strong> to change <strong>this<strong> text, 
but <strong>I can't<strong>. <strong>Why?<strong>.
```

I'm using the following regex:

```
\x26lt;(.*?)\x26gt;
```

(globally, and replacing it with "`<$1>`")

I guess the problem is I can't tell how many matches will be found, and how to refer to each one. Maybe in Perl I could have used $+, but that isn't working. I'm doing this with the regex module of Yahoo Pipes. It should be very similar to PHP implemenations, afaik.

How can I use each match separately in Yahoo Pipes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be easier to replace the `&lt;` and the `&gt;` independently. That way it becomes a simply find-replace that doesn't need to use back-references.

Comment: would I need to do two passes for that? one to change the &lt;s and another for the &gt;s? (thanks!)

Comment: It would be two passes. Just do a string replace on &lt; and &gt; and then inject your new string into the web page.

Comment: I'm not intimately familiar with Yahoo Pipes, but most regular expression engines have a replace all functionality of some sort. You would have to `replaceAll("&lt;", "<")` and `replaceAll("&gt;", ">")`, so yes, two operations would be required.

Comment: Oh. Seems I always get too greedy when doing regular expressions. I was hoping there was a one liner I didn't know so I wouldn't have to do 2 passes. The back references was one hope that almost worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do a single operation if you check the `g` checkbox, like in this screenshot...:
[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [aleax.it](http://www.aleax.it/Picture%201.png))</sub>